# VM param optimization - Tomcat 7 and JDK 1.6

Tags: optimization, tomcat7, java-6

**Deployment Env (web server only)**

> 1. 16 GB RAM
> 2. Doble XEON processor (Intel)
> 3. Centos 5.5 as OS
> 4. Tomcat 7
> 5. JDK 1.6

Question is what would be best VM param and Connector options and for tomcat?

Current Connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
maxThreads="1000" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="200"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
```

JV param :

```
-server -Xms10G -Xmx10G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-TraceClassUnloading 
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000
```

Thanks.